# Protegento métodos de uma DLL

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, .net-assembly, visibilidade

Tenho uma DLL que possui diversos métodos internos, desejo proteger estes métodos internos para que sejam chamados apenas pela própria DLL.

Há alguma maneira de definir quais métodos podem ou não ser chamados externamente a DLL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, deve usar o [`internal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) em cada método que só possa ser chamado pela DLL.

A classe toda pode ser `internal`também. Na verdade este é o padrão.

Ele pode ser usado com `protected` também, já que este restritor tem a ver com herança e não com a visibilidade simples.

Algo assim:

```
public class Tricycle {
    //só pode ser acessado por tipos dentro da DLL
    internal void Pedal() { }
    //pode ser acessado por uma classe qualquer que derive desta, ou tipos desta DLL.
    protected internal int Wheels => { get; } => 3
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Internal.cs)